# How to change the name of a collection or db in a Mongoose provider dynamically, Nestjs?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I would need to change where my queries are pointing in a Nestjs app.

I am working in an Angular app with versions so I have to change collections or even databases dinamically in my back end with Mongoose and Nestjs.

I suppose I have to change target in the provider and try to change it dynamically depending of what version the user have chosen in the front.

Anyway I have sth like

```
import { Connection } from 'mongoose';
import { TestSchema } from './schemas/test.schema';
    export const testProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'TestModelToken',
    useFactory: (connection: Connection) =>
      connection.model('Test', FilterSchema, 'tests'),

    inject: ['DbConnectionToken'],
  },
];
```

And later, for example, I want to change it to dynamically point to this collection

```
tests_24_04_2019
```

My service looks like

```
@Injectable()
export class TestsService {
  constructor(
    @Inject("TestModelToken") private readonly testModel: Model<Test>,
```

Thanks, I appreciate any help

Comment: what version of nestjs are you using?

Comment: Nestjs 5.4.x :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Nestjs, but I think you should initialize the collection model on the runtime instead of creating it directly in provider

```js
 {
    provide: 'TestModelToken',
    useFactory: (connection: Connection) => {
        getTestModel(version: string) => connection.model('Test', FilterSchema, `tests_${version}`),
    }
    inject: ['DbConnectionToken'],
 },
```

Comment: Absolutely, however in my use case I don't know the collection a priori or before so that why I have to change it dynamically